# How to set a base class internal field

Tags: .net, reflection, field, internal, account-management

Im extending a class (DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal) and I need to assign a value to a field in the base class but its marked internal. Can I use reflection to set the value? How would that be done?

I found this:

```
base.GetType().GetProperty("unpersisted").SetValue(??, false);
```

But im not quite sure how to give it the base Principal object

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **this** for ??

Comment: Sorry I take that back your correct, I just had to use GetField instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GetProperty on the derived class and use all parameters as this:

```
GetType(Derived).GetProperty("BaseProperty", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing, GetType(PropertyType), New Type() {}, Nothing).SetValue(DerivedInstance, NewValue, Nothing)
```